# Compositor - Frameserver Input

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

I use the VSE for editing a lot of screen recordings, and would like to take the output from these editing sessions and use them in the compositor. As far as I can tell, the only way to do so is to render everything out ahead of time and use a video input.

Is it possible to use one instance of Blender as a frame server and use that server in the compositor of another instance? Alternatively, is there any way to do this in one process, frame server or not?

Answer (score 1):

Open a new instance of Blender.
Set the project render settings; render size, # of frames, output etc.
Switch to the compositor view.
In the compositor; select use nodes, then with your mouse over the Node editor window press "SHIFT + A" on the keyboard, and select Input -> Image. In the node that appears click Open, then navigate to the directory containing the image sequence you wish to process, and select the frames to use (images should be named as frame numbers i.e. 001.png 002.png etc)

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That still involves rendering everything out ahead of time, then loading it into another instance. I'd prefer the frame server so I can edit the "source," restart the server, and have the second Blender instance pull in those changes.